# Best way to secure Spring Boot & Angular app with SSL

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, nginx, ssl

What is the best way to implement SSL in Spring Boot & Angular application (frontend with backend)?

1. Should I configure SSL in both applications separately?
2. Or should I configure SSL in Nginx web server and not taking care about securing applications?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I configure SSL in both applications separately?

If you've built out a microservice architecture and both your spring boot application and your Angular application are served off different domains, then yes you should configure SSL on both applications.

> Or should I configure SSL in Nginx web server and not taking care about securing applications?

If you are using NGINX to serve your Angular application, then yes you should setup SSL on it.

I'll add that SSL is not the only step required to secure an application. Many applications will require some user management with role based permissions and control access to screens in your app or REST APIs based on user permissions.